# How to delete the personal profile in the Samsung Contacts app?

Tags: contacts, samsung-one-ui

Is it possible to delete the personal profile that is created in the Galaxy Contacts app? The personal profile section appears directly at the top above the contacts list, under "My profile".

After creating the profile it doesn't seem possible to delete it (I can only edit it - but I want it removed).

I am using One UI 5.0 (Android 13) and the Contacts app version is 14.0.05.8

The profile isn't linked to any Samsung account. The Samsung Contacts app personal profile seems to be stored locally on the phone. I tried clearing the Contacts app data & cache but this didn't remove the personal profile unfortunately.